# JQuery Date picker not working in view

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-5.1

i have the below code to get a date picker for a view, some how the below code is not working i am not sure where i am going wrong, could anyone help me to get the below needs 
1.  i should have a date picker and when the user submits i want to values selected by the user

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h4>Welcome @Session["LoginName"]</h4>
<h4>@ViewBag.LoginId</h4>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
     $(function () {
         $("#MyDate").datepicker();
     });
</script>
@using (Html.BeginForm("ValidateUser", "Login", FormMethod.Post))
{

<h3>Select Bussiness Date </h3>
<div>
    <input type="text" id="MyDate" />
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
        <input type="submit" value="Continue" class="btn btn-default" />
    </div>
</div>

}


<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You have `jquery` twice, and the 2nd one wipes out `jquery-ui`

Comment: i removed below jquery part from the code still no luck

Comment: No luck with what? _Its not working_ is not a question! Explain what the error is.

Comment: Post your ActionResult ValidateUser, my friend.

Comment: @StephenMuecke No luck means - even after removing the duplicate jQuery statements i do not get see the date picker working i.e a date picker is not displayed when i click on the text field

Comment: @brijesh Please check if the layout page has these query. Please check the view source at runtime ie (Browser). If you can inspect the page there must be error such as [http://prntscr.com/fbxfq3]

Answer (score 0):

remove these lines from the begin of your view

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
 $(function () {
     $("#MyDate").datepicker();
 });
</script>
```

and change the last lines like this

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
     $(function () {
         $("#MyDate").datepicker();
     });
</script>
```

1-It's Better To Place Your Script Files at End Of Document

2-You Had Duplicated Jquery Files So You Get the Error